# NodeJs validator function not defined

Tags: node.js, npm

I installed validator module via npm.I am loading the module via this code:

```
var check = require('validator').check,
    sanitize = require('validator').sanitize;
```

It loads perfectly but when I run this line

```
data.message = sanitize(data.message).escape();
```

I am getting "TypeError: undefined is not a function" for this line.How can I resolve it ?

Comment: According to the source code found here: https://github.com/chriso/validator.js/blob/master/validator.js there's no function named 'sanitize'

Comment: I see now,it deprecated by author.How can I resolve this ? It's important for me.

Comment: What is it that you want to do with the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this library that you might want to use instead:

https://www.npmjs.org/package/google-caja

https://github.com/superkhau/node-google-caja

Comment: I didn't understand how can I use this in node.js

Answer (score 0):

I read that you need specifically an xss filter. So, directly from the [github main page of Validator](https://github.com/chriso/validator.js#xss-sanitization):

> ### XSS Sanitization
>
> XSS sanitization was removed from the library in 2d5d6999.
>   For an alternative, look at Yahoo's [xss-filters](https://github.com/yahoo/xss-filters) library.

#### From xss-filters tutorial

Firstly, import:

```
var xssFilters = require('xss-filters');
```

Then escape it:

```
data.message = xssFilters.inHTMLData(data.message);
```